# Netty HttpResponseStatus

Tags: netty

```
private HttpResponseStatus(int code, String reasonPhrase, boolean bytes)
{
    if(code < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException((new StringBuilder()).append("code: ").append(code).append(" (expected: 0+)").toString());
    if(reasonPhrase == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("reasonPhrase");
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        if(i >= reasonPhrase.length())
            break;
        char c = reasonPhrase.charAt(i);
        switch(c)
        {
        case 10: // '\n'
        case 13: // '\r'
            throw new IllegalArgumentException((new StringBuilder()).append("reasonPhrase contains one of the following prohibited characters: \\r\\n: ").append(reasonPhrase).toString());
        }
        i++;
    } while(true);
    this.code = code;
    codeAsText = new AsciiString(Integer.toString(code));
    this.reasonPhrase = reasonPhrase;
    if(bytes)
        this.bytes = (new StringBuilder()).append(code).append(" ").append(reasonPhrase).toString().getBytes(CharsetUtil.US_ASCII);
    else
        this.bytes = null;
}
```

This code is part of "io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus".

I don't know what the value, "String reasonPhrase" mean.

What value do I give "reasonPhrase"?

My Netty version is 4.1.19.Final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason phrase is part of the status line in the HTTP response. For example, in `200 OK`, `OK` is the reason phrase.

You almost never need to provide your own reason phrase (or indeed construct your own `HttpResponseStatus`). The most common response statuses are defined as constants in the `HttpResponseStatus` class. For example, to create an HTTP response of `200 OK` with a body, the code looks like:

```
FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(
            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK, buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a code, but want an HTTP Status code, instead use the static method to generate an HTTP response status object from an integer.

https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpResponseStatus.html#valueOf-int-